# Upload image with c# & angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, upload, photo

I'm trying to upload an image with c# & angular. This is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadedImage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this.files)" accept="image/*" />
```

and this is my JAVASCRIPT (angular):

```
$scope.uploadImage = function (files) {
    $http.post('WebServices/WSFileUpload.asmx/UploadFile', { file: files }).success(function (response) {
        $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple()
                .textContent("RESULT: " + response.d)
                .hideDelay(toastTime)
        );
    })
}
```

My C# right now is: (super basic, just to make sure the system can upload a file)

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public bool UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/images"));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

and it throws an error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'.
```

Why is that?